# Android Volley getting response from login php but not going to next activity

Tags: php, android, mysql

Android Login problem. Php is perfectly returning the response in JSON format. But the android activity is not going to next activity. sometimes it is showing Bad network connection and sometimes it is showing passwords don't match error even though the right password

here are my codes

login.php

```
  <?php

include("Connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{

   $email=$_POST["email"];

   $password=$_POST["password"];

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user_master where email='$email' && password='$password'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {   
        $isLogin["success"] = 1;

    }           
    else
    {   
        $isLogin["success"] = 0;
    }
    echo json_encode($isLogin);
}


?>
```

LoginRequest.java

```
    package com.talentakeaways.ttpms;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;



import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by chand on 15-03-2018.
 */

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {


    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.9:80/Ttpms/login.php";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, listener, errorListener);
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("email", username);
        parameters.put("password", password);
    }
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

Ttpm_Login.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ttpm_login);
        setTitle("Login"); //set title of the activity
        initialize();
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Ttpm_Login.this);
        //onClickListener method for button
        bt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //assigning String variables to the text in edit texts
                userName = tenantname.getText().toString();
                password = passWord.getText().toString();
                //Validating the String values
                if (validateUsername(userName) && validatePassword(password)) {

                    //Start ProgressDialog
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Ttpm_Login.this);
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging You In");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.show();


                    //LoginRequest from class LoginRequest
                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(userName, password, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.i("Login Response", response);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                //If Success then start Dashboard Activity
                                if (jsonObject.getString("success").equals(1)) {
                                    Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Ttpm_Dashboard.class);
                                    startActivity(loginSuccess);
                                    finish();
                                }

                                //else Invalid
                                else {
                                    if (jsonObject.getString("success").equals(0))
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                    else {
//                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords Don't Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Bad Response from the Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Connection Timed Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Bad Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(loginRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Please help thanks In advance.

Comment: also  you can try 
if (jsonObject.getString("success").equalsIgnoreCase("1"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing JSON result with an number which is wrong

try this

```
   if (jsonObject.getString("success").equals("1"))  {
      // Proceed to Login
   }  else { 
          if (jsonObject.getString("success").equals("0")) {
   }
```

Server is returning `{ "success" : "1" }`

Comment: Thanks It worked but I have to make the change in php also.

Answer (score 0):

Write this block above `if..else` condition in `PHP` file as

```
$isLogin["success"] = 0; //This will give access outside of If condition.
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{   
    $isLogin["success"] = 1;

}           

echo json_encode($isLogin);
```

And as @Lucifer posted, the server is returning `{"success":"1"}`, in your `Activity`'s code write your as

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
if(jsonObject.getString("success").equals("1"))
{
     //Success
}
else{
    //Invalid Login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it is very help full to you:

```
    String url = Global.BASE_URL + Global.LOGIN_API;
    cancel_login_api=url;
    StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                /** Api response action*/
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                      Log.e("AB",response);
                     /** receiving response from api here*/
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (API.success(obj))
                        {

                            Utils.storeUserPreferences(LoginActivity.this, Global.USER, API.getData(obj));
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, API.rMessage(obj), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent skip = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(skip);
                        } else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+API.rMessage(obj), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }   catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("AA",response);
                    }

                    /** Alert dialog box is dismiss*/
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        /** method when no response from internet*/
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            /** Error Log */
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.e("AA",""+error.getMessage());

            /** Alert dialog box is dismiss*/
            pd.dismiss();
        }
      }) {

        /*
        ** Sending parameters to server
        * @params user_login
        * @params user_login_password
        */

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

          /** Pass the parameters to according to the API.*/
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_login", edt_email.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("user_login_password", edt_password.getText().toString().trim());
            return params;
        }
    };
    /** Adding request to request queue*/
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, cancel_login_api);
}
```

try this.